# Use JavaScript Functions in Column Templates kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have function here and I want to call it in **kendo** column.Function is checking if class is clicked.But when I add that  class in **kendo** column nothing happend, whats i am doing here? Could you help me to call that class in **kendo** column ?

Thanks

```
            <script>
$(function() {
    $(".createInvoice").on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        var self = $(this);

        var createInvoiceW = $("#createInvoiceWindow");
        var kwindow = createInvoiceW.data("kendoWindow");

        kwindow.refresh({
            url: "@Url.Action("CreateInvoicePopup", "Finances")/" + self.data('job-id')
        });
        kwindow.center();
        kwindow.open();
    });
});
            </script>

            <div id="createInvoiceWindow" class="kWindow"
                 data-title="false"
                 data-width="600"
                 @* data-height="700"*@
                 data-ajax="true"
                 data-visible="false"
                 data-url="@Url.Action("CreateInvoicePopup", "Finances")"></div>
```

kendo grid

```
   <div id="jobs-grid"></div>@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Modus.Presentation.Models.Jobs.JobModel>()
  .Name("#jobs-grid")
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .Read(read => read.Action("List", "Jobs"))
   )
  .Columns(columns =>
  {

  columns.Bound(product => product.JobNumber).ClientTemplate("<a href='" +

     "/#= Id #'" +
 ">Show Product Details</a>").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "createInvoice"        });
  columns.Bound(product => product.Customer.Name).ClientTemplate("<a class='createInvoice'>hgg</a>");
  columns.Bound(product => product.Customer.Name).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "createInvoice" });

  columns.Bound(p => p.JobNumber).Template(@<text>
                @Html.ActionLink("", "", new { id = @item.Id , @class= "createInvoice" })>
</text>);


  })
      .Pageable()

                    )
```